# nodeValue, data, textContent, wholeText, innerHTML don't work

Tags: javascript

I have the following text node:

```
                    <content ID="med1">
                    Medication: Albuterol inhalant<br/>
                    Instructions: 2 puffs QID PRN wheezing<br/>
                    Status: Active
                    </content>
```

I get the content node like this:

```
var content = items[i].getElementsByTagName("content")[0];
```

and then try:

```
    var item = content.childNodes[0].textContent;  //returns "Medication: Albuterol inhalant"
```

instead of textContent I have tried data, nodeValue, and wholeText.  They all return the same thing.

I have also tried innerHTML and innerText which both return "undefined"

I want the entire text.  How to prevent the `<br/>` from truncating the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `childNodes[0]`:

```
var item = content.textContent;
```

Comment: That worked but now it ignored the new line.  Result: Medication: Albuterol inhalant Instructions: 2 puffs QID PRN wheezing Status: Active.  I'm inserting the text into an unordered list and want it to show up like this: * Albuterol inhalant/nInstructions: 2 puffs QID PRN wheezing/nStatus: Active.

Comment: That worked, although I had to use '<br>' instead of '/n' because alert apparently interprets line breaks differently

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
var item = document.getElementById('med1').textContent;
alert(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

try `innerText`

```
var c = document.getElementById('med1');
alert(c.innerText)
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9qSqs/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use jQuery?

```
var text = $( "content[ID='med1']" ).text();
```